# How to hide unrelated links?

Tags: jsp

I have following code

```
<body>

<%
    String loggedInUserName = (String) request.getAttribute("loggedInUserName");
%>
<%
    String userRole = "lead";
%>
<%
    if (loggedInUserName.equals(userRole)) { %>    
    <%@ include file="tabs.jsp"%>

<a href="dataOwner-index.html" style="visibility: hidden"></a>
<a href="dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html"style="visibility: hidden"></a>
<a href="security_setup.html" style="visibility: hidden"></a>
<%
    }
%>
```

And tabs.jsp contains

```
<div class="tslcNav" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="mngPost.html">Manage Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="riskAssesment.html">Risk Assesment</a></li>
            <li><a href="securitySetup.html">Security Setup</a></li>
            <li><a href="dataOwner-index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html">Assessment Workbook</a></li>
            <li><a href="security_setup.html">Security Setup</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Whats wrong with this code?It is displaying all tabs.I want to show only those tabs which are related to lead I want hide other links i.e, tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It shows all tabs because you are including the whole `tabs.jsp` with this line

> <%@ include file="tabs.jsp"%

And the three lines that you have after just add three new `<a>` with hidden style to the generated HTML page after your tabs.

What you need to fix this issue is first to remove these lines

```
<a href="dataOwner-index.html" style="visibility: hidden"></a>
<a href="dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html"style="visibility: hidden"></a>
<a href="security_setup.html" style="visibility: hidden"></a>
```

to only apply the style hidden only on tabs that you don't wish to display in `tabs.jsp`, you can do it using [`el`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) like this

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="mngPost.html">Manage Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="riskAssesment.html">Risk Assesment</a></li>
<li><a href="securitySetup.html">Security Setup</a></li>

<li><a href="dataOwner-index.html" ${ loggedInUserName eq userRole ? 'style="visibility: hidden"' : '' }>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="dataOwner-riskAssessmentCompliance.html" ${ loggedInUserName eq userRole ? 'style="visibility: hidden"' : '' }>Assessment Workbook</a></li>
<li><a href="security_setup.html" ${ loggedInUserName eq userRole ? 'style="visibility: hidden"' : '' }>Security Setup</a></li>
```